# Byobu, get the status bar of tmux backend the same as screen backend

Tags: byobu

When I use screen as the back-end of byobu, I'm getting a status bar which is composed of only black and red or black and yellow. And it looks more professional. But when I choose tmux as back-end I'm getting the status bar which composed of more colors and bold font's which I doesn't like that much. Can I make the status bar of byobu the same as screen  back-end, when I use tmux as my back-end? Thanks for the help.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can go back to using the Screen backend, if you want.  Just run [byobu-select-backend](http://manpg.es/byobu-select-backend):

```
$ byobu-select-backend 

Select the byobu backend:
  1. tmux
  2. screen

Choose 1-2 [1]: 2
```

*Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*

Comment: Yes. I used to screen as back-end. Recently moved to tmux. I really wanted to have that status bar. Thanks for reply, I will stop my experiments with .tmux.conf now..